# Кривой редирект в code igniter

Tags: redirect, php, codeigniter

Всем привет.
Возникла проблема, при редиректе из локальной области метода на локальную область центрального класса, редирект не происходит, т.е. получается что-то типо этого:
site.ru/class/method1 -> site.ru/class/method1/method2, вместо этого нужно что бы было:
site.ru/class/method1 -> site.su/class/method2. Использую только html ссылку, без использования хелперов и т.д. Пробовал уже и роутинг, и в самом методе вычислять сегмент и редиректить через redirect(), ничего не выходит.

Comment: Миссия выполнена. Возвращаемся домой.

Comment: Не забудьте составить рапорт и выложить его сюда в качестве ответа на свой вопрос :)
А то в аду приготовлен специальный котел для тех, кто вместо описания решения пишет что-то типа "всем спасибо, проблема решена"